# Wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 1..3). - Search bar set up

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very new to Rails, so please bear with me. I'm currently trying to add a search widget to my homepage (room booking app).
All I need users to do is to select one of the room attributes (home_type) from the drop down menu and then click the button "search" to see the results. So here is what I'm struggling with:

How should I structure the search part on the homepage. With the approach below I'm getting an error of Argument Error in Pages#home. Wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 1..3).

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= select_tag :room, params[:room], [["Apartment", "Apartment"], ["House", "House"]], id: "room", prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
     <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-normal btn-block" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm trying to adapt parts of an airbnb tutorial to my needs, so not sure if I'm doing it right.

Comment: The error is very straight forward, did you read the documentation? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-select-and-option-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like this

```
select_tag :room, [["Apartment", "Apartment"], ["House", "House"]], id: "room", prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control"
```

Note, that to set a value from params you`ll